# Problem installing Wine in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine, 20.04

I have a problem installing Wine after installing the latest upgrade.

[image]

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:  
NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F  
Reading package lists... Done
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:   
NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F  
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/bionic InRelease' is not signed.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore  
disabled by default.  
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and other user configuration details.
```

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste the output as text instead of as a screenshot of a window of a program with text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: The first command is wrong. You added a repo for Ubuntu 18.04. Everything else is the consequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the references to *https://dl/winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic* as the good folks at WineHQ are not supporting focal, as seen in https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/